# Braced initialization in C++03

Tags: c++, c++03, c++builder-xe5

Is this program supposed to correctly initialize the string, in C++03?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A
{
    std::string s;
};

int main()
{
    A a = { };
    std::cout << a.s.size() << std::endl;

}
```

Using bcc32 6.70, the output is `256` , and inspecting the string in the debugger, its internal pointers appear to be garbage addresses.

Comment: What on earth is bcc32?

Comment: @KerrekSB A compiler

Comment: Barely so, by the look of it :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB I can't remember the exact rules for initialization pre c++11  also , in this compiler, `struct B : A { B(): A() {} };` does the same thing. Maybe it is using C++98 rules

Comment: Even in C++98, default-initializing an `std::string` cannot possibly have been allowed to bypass the default constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A` is an [aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178176/241631) and C++03 allows initialization of aggregates using a braced initializer-list. If the initializer-list is empty, then each member of the aggregate is value initialized.

From C++03 *[dcl.init.aggr]/8*

> ... An empty initializer-list can be used to initialize any aggregate. If the aggregate is not an empty class, then each member of the aggregate shall be initialized with a value of the form `T()` (5.2.3), where `T` represents the type of the uninitialized member.

In your example the `std::string` member should be default initialized.

Comment: Thanks. Is C++98 the same?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm not sure. C++98 didn't have value initialization, but even so, in this case I'd be very surprised if the default constructor for `std::string` was not required to be called.